# Jmeter client certificate setting gives 403 error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Im using apache jmeter 5.3
My remote service requires client certificate when making calls.
I followed the steps pointed in this article[1] (Options-->SSL manager , and selected my cert, provided password)

But still I get 403. Anyone can help?

Same certificate is working when I configure it via Postman.

[1]https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status code 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) means "Forbidden", in other words:

- The server recognizes the user as the valid one (authentication passes)
- However the server doesn't allow the user to access the particular resource (authorization fails)

Also be aware that SSL Manager will work in GUI mode only, if you're running your test in command-line non-GUI mode you will need to put the path to the keystore and the password into *system.properties* file, see [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) article for more details.

In case of problems take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally it contains sufficient amount of troubleshooting information, if it doesn't - your can always increase log level verbosity for the component(s) you're interested in.